# How to keep the cell reference in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Lets say I have the following data:

```
    A   B   C
1  =B1 
2  =C2
3  =C3
```

I want to write a macro than can add text around the values in column A without losing the reference.

For example

```
    A               B   C
1   [Hello].[1]     1      
2   [Hello].[20]       20  
3   [Hello].[10]       10
```

As an example for A1 I use:

.cells(1,1) = "[Hello].[" & .cell(1,2) & "]"

This give me the wanted value but in the end I lose the cell reference in A1.

I rather want this:

```
    A                B   C
1   [Hello].[B1]     1      
2   [Hello].[C2]        20  
3   [Hello].[C3]        10
```

Of course with the actual value of the reference and not just the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
With .cells(1,1) 
   .value = "=" & .cell(1,2).address
   .format= ""[Hello].[" 0 "]""
End With
```

this should do. more info on this excel exotic syntax on that random website https://exceljet.net/custom-number-formats
best of luck, but consider using another language than vba